# Visual C: Custom Error Message in Template Class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-assert

The code below fails (as expected). What bothers me is the error message. It does not clearly say what the problem is. I would have expected something like `“cannot convert from const char* to int”`. Instead, it says `"cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'B<int>'"`, which becomes less clear when other, complex, types are involved.

How do I add a **custom error message**? The actual class is much more complicated.

```
#include <vector>

template< typename T >
class B
{
  std::vector<T> v;
public:
  B( std::initializer_list<T> il ) : v{ il } {}
};

int main()
{
  B<int> b{ "a","b","c" }; // fails with cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'B<int>'
}
```

Comment: I know of one way but it requires that you only have an initializer_list constructor.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, it is. If you are thinking at deleting the copy constructor, I have already tried - with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to have a `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor then one thing you can do is provide a variadic template constructor and then have a `static_assert` inside the constructor that gives the error message that you want.  This works because if you provide anything other then an `std::initializer_list<T>` the constructor will be a better match and the assert will fire.  That would look like

```
#include <vector>

template< typename T >
class B
{
    std::vector<T> v;
public:
    B( std::initializer_list<T> il ) : v{ il } {}
    template <typename... Args>
    // the sizeof...(Args) < 0 is needed so the assert will only fire if the constructor is called
    B(Args...) { static_assert(sizeof...(Args) < 0, "This class can only be constructed from a std::initializer_list<T>"); }
};

int main()
{
    //B<int> b1{ "a","b","c" }; // uncomment this line to get static_assert to fire
    B<int> b2{ 1,2,3 };
}
```